# Looping images in div element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner starting to learn coding. I have designed an neuroscience related experiment on a webpage with 4  layers of webpage. my first layer will be constant. Second layer shows different images during each round of questioning. Third and fourth layer are questions displayed at certain time intervals and/or on click of submit. I would like to know how do i display the different images every time. Precisely, Can i do it using a for loop!?

```
<html>

<head>
<Title> Experiment </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="displayfieldset.css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Layer 1 of cross hair image -->
<div id="crosshair" style="background-color:black; position:absolute;     width:100%; height:100%; z-index:1; align:center">
<img src="crosshair.jpg" width="1350px" height="750px" >
</div> <!-- Layer 1 closed -->

<!-- Layer 2 of Images -->
<div id="piclayer" style="position:absolute ;width:98%; height:98%; z-    index:2; align:center; margin-left:0.5%; margin-top:0.5%">
    <img id="images" src="image1.jpg" style="width:1325px; height:720px; display:none">
</div> <!-- Layer 2 closed -->


<!-- Layer 3 Question 1 -->
<div id="questionone" style="z-index:3; position:absolute; display:none; margin-left: 180px">
<fieldset name="field1_1" id="field1_1">
<form name ="problem1_1" id="problem1_1"  >
  <b> Identify the problem shown in this image. </b>
  <br> 
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="answer1_1" id="answer1_1" maxlength="30" style="width: 400px">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="showdiv()"  >
</form>
</fieldset>
</div>

<!-- Layer 4 Question 2 -->
<div id="questiontwo" style=" position: absolute; z-index:5; align:center; display:none; margin-left: 180px">
<fieldset name="field1_2" id="field1_2" style="position:relative; align:center">
<form name ="problem1_2" id="problem1_2" >
  <b> Propose a solution to the problem. </b>
  <br> 
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="solution1_2" id="solution1_2" maxlength="30" style="height: 200px; width: 400px">
  <br>
  <br> 
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="hidediv()" >
  </form>
</fieldset>
</div>

<script>
  function showdiv()
  {
    document.getElementById('questiontwo').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('questionone').style.display = "none";
  }

  function hidediv()
  {
   document.getElementById('piclayer').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('questionone').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('questiontwo').style.display = 'none';
  }

  <!-- Time out for image -->
  setTimeout 
  ( function()
    {
      document.getElementById('images').style.display = 'block';
    }
    ,6000
  );

  <!-- Timeout for first question -->
  setTimeout 
  ( function()
   {
    document.getElementById('questionone').style.display = 'block';
   }
   ,12000
  );
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, first assign them an identical class name and then get all of them by `document.getElementsByClassName`. This method gives you a list of all those images which you can loop through and to do anything you want.

Comment: Have you tried placing different <img> tags within the different <div> tags?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your coding,
The "crosshair" image, layer-1 is show always at z-index:1.
Layer-2 images will show after 6 seconds of page load at z-index:2.
Layer-3 div will show after 12 seconds of page load at z-index:3.
In the Layer-3, there is a submit button. If user click on the Submit button,
Layer-4 will be display and Layer-3 will be hide.
There is a submit button inside Layer-4 again, if user click on that button, all images will be hidden. 
So, what you want to do?

Do you want to show images from Layer-2 by looping? If yes, here is sample codes:

```js
var x = 0;
function myFunction(){  
   
   var Layer2Images = document.querySelectorAll("img.images"); 
   if (x == Layer2Images.length)
      x=0;
   for (i = 0; i < Layer2Images.length; i++) {
    Layer2Images[i].style.display = 'none';
   }
   Layer2Images[x].style.display = 'block';
   x++;
}

setInterval(myFunction, 1000)
```

```html
<!-- Layer 2 of Images -->
<div id="piclayer" style="position:absolute ;width:98%; height:98%; z-index:2; align:center; margin-left:0.5%; margin-top:0.5%">
   <img class="images" src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/05/29/00/43/car-49278_1280.jpg" style="width:400px;height:300px; display:none;">
   <img class="images" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/24353/pexels-photo-large.jpg" style="width:400px; height:300px; display:none;">
   <img class="images" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/16155/pexels-photo-large.jpg" style="width:400px; height:300px; display:none;">
</div> <!-- Layer 2 closed -->
```

Comment: Your understanding is perfectly right. So on layer 4 (z-index 4) there is again a submit button. Clicking that will repeat the event from layer 2 , 3 and 4 as it happened earlier but with a different image in layer 2.

Comment: I would like to know the purpose of document.querySelectorAll("img.images")

Comment: document.querySelectorAll("img.images")  is to get all <img> html elements with class name "images". We given all images <img> tags' class name as "images". [<img class="images ...." .....>]

Comment: Alright! And here, the images are displayed in an interval of 1 second if I'm not wrong. Would you please help out in how to do the same when the 'submit' button in layer 4 is clicked?

Comment: To be precise, Image in layer 2 should change only when the submit is clicked in layer 4. It is not timed. Consider the following steps

-> Layer 1 black screen appears for 6 seconds
-> Layer 2 with image 1 appears for 6 seconds
-> QUestion 1 appears in layer 3

Comment: -> On submit, question 2 appears in layer 4.

Comment: On submitting that, layer 2, 3 and 4 hide. Only layer 1 appears for 6 seconds. Now layer 2 is appearing again after the 6 seconds and this time, image is different. And same procedure, after 6 seconds, question 1 and on submit question 2 appears. On submitting question 2 , layer 1 again appears for 6 seconds. And then Layer 2 with image 3 for 6 seconds

Comment: How about if I want to include the onclick (layer 3 and layer 4 functions) in this loop?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). With those you can target a single DOM node by CSS query selector or you can target multiple DOM all at once and then loop over them in a for of loop by converting the nodes to an array with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

**Full working example**

```js
let i = 0

// Grab all the layers and read them into an array so we can iterate them.
let layers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img.layer'))
const nextLayer = () => {
  // increment i and compare incremented value, if greater than 3, reset to first layer.
  if(++i > 3)
    i = 1
  // iterate all layers and set their CSS display property to none.
  layers.forEach((x) => { x.style.display = 'none' })
  // select the single layer we are currently on and set its css display to block.
  document.querySelector(`img.layer_${i}`).style.display = 'block'
}

// show first layer
nextLayer()
// show next layer every 2 seconds
setInterval(nextLayer, 2000)
```

```html
<img class="layer layer_1" src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg" />
<img class="layer layer_2" src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg" />
<img class="layer layer_3" src="http://livewallpaper.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Desktop-Cute-Wallpapers-HD-1920x1080-1.jpg" />
```